# error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{} | T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I found this examlpe for async pipe error handling for Angular which looked promising: https://sebastian-holstein.de/post/error-handling-angular-async-pipe/

Trying to run it in angular 7 though causes compilation errors

```
readonly data$: Observable<T>;

  constructor(data: Observable<T>) {
    this.data$ = data.pipe(
      shareReplay(1),
      catchError(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this._errorLoading$.next(true);
        return of();
      })
    );
  }
```

Error:

```
ERROR in src/app/loading-wrapper.ts(12,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{} | T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'.
  Type '{} | T' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Full class

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: How do you call this constructor ? What variable type is passed to it ?

Comment: Added a picture of the full class to the question now.

Answer (score 7):

It's because you do `return of();`, and the value being passed to `of` is not of type `T`.

You can instead do `return of(null);`, or ensure you pass a value of type T to the `of` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this declaration:

```
readonly data$: Observable<{} | T>;
```